# Using python to pause and play a movie in netflix

Tags: python, selenium, netflix

I recently started a project in which I use python to start/stop and further down the line manipulate sound in netflix, I'm currently working on finding a way to use python to pause and play the video, but I'm confuse as to which is the best way to accomplish this, I atempted to use selenium webdriver and try to find the tag by id, but im not having any luck with that since netflix disabled "inspect element", is there any other wayto do it besides using element Id or class name?

Comment: you can just send key space

Comment: im having trouble finding the element to which ill sent the key space

Comment: just send it to document

Answer (score 0):

You can try using [PyAutoGUI](https://pypi.org/project/PyAutoGUI/) to send space keys on your browser.

Sample program to pause and unpause after 10 minutes:

```
import pyautogui, time
pyautogui.press('space')
time.sleep(600)  # 10 mins
pyautogui.press('space')
```